# Siddhi Query from Redis

Tags: siddhi

seem like i have an issue with Siddhi query from redis.
Below code doesn't print any OutputStream.
I have key in redis name as fo1

```
       "@store(type='redis', host='x.x.x.x', port='6379', table.name='RedisTable')" +
        "@PrimaryKey('key')" +
        "define table RedisTable(key string, value string); " +

        "define stream FooStream (name string); " +
        "define stream OutputStream(name string); " +
        "from FooStream  " +
        "[( RedisTable.key == name ) in RedisTable] " +
        "insert into OutputStream; ";

        SiddhiAppRuntime siddhiAppRuntime = siddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(streams );

        //Adding callback to retrieve output events from stream
        siddhiAppRuntime.addCallback("OutputStream", new StreamCallback() {
            @Override
            public void receive(Event[] events) {
                EventPrinter.print(events);
                //To convert and print event as a map
                //EventPrinter.print(toMap(events));
            }
        });

        InputHandler inputHandler = siddhiAppRuntime.getInputHandler("FooStream");
        inputHandler.send(new Object[]{"fo1"});
```

Redis :
[image]

I expecting and output of 'fo1' for OutputStream but somehow it doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this help you but my configuration for redis is :

```
@Store(type="redis", table.name="tablename", cluster.mode="false", nodes="redisIP:6379")
 @primaryKey('key')
define table tablename (foo string)
```

Im using wso2sp, but maybe this help you.